# Finding a closed formula or an asymptotic bound

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

Can we find closed form of the formula

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{[\frac{n}{2}]} {n \choose i}(\sum_{j=i}^{n-i}{n-i\choose
j}-\frac{1}{2}{n-i \choose i})
$$

or, if not, is it possible to determine some asymptotic bound of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the brackets correctly, then for $n \ge 1$ the values seem to be $0,1,6,25,90,301,\ldots$ which seems to be $$\tfrac12 3^n-2^n+\tfrac12$$ related to [OEIS A000392](https://oeis.org/A000392)